# Accessing the contents of an array Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a json structure like this 
I am trying to check for the "type" in each nested widgets array.So if it is of a certain type then i am trying to extract properties like fade steps,width, height etc.

Is there a way of doing it using the for loop?
Right now I am doing like this:

```
for (NSString *widgetArray in widgets)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", widgetArray);
}
```

Its printing the contents, How do I extract corresponding values?
    for(NSDictionary *asset in [assets allValues])
    {
        NSString *type = asset[@"type"];

```
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"gradient"])
    {
        [gradients addObject:asset];

    }
```

This is the pseudo code provided by one of the members which helped me access the contents of the dictionary, I am not able to apply a similar logic to the nested array structure.

Comment: use `objectAtIndex:` for arrays, `objectForKey:` for dictionaries, or subscripting (like `array[0]` or `dict[@"foo"]`).

Comment: Lets make sure the JSON is contained first. Is the contents of this JSON contained within `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`s, or are we dealing with a JSON `NSString`?

Comment: @WDUK It is a JSON String. The structure of it is an outer dictionary, within which there is a dictionary and an array with a nested structure. With the help of stack overflow, I could get the values of the dictionary, but I am having a hard time accessing the contents of this array with the key "type", Please observe that this will be only the constant key, this defines what are the other entries

Comment: The Q is about recursive `widgets` key? So every widget can have another widgets? And you want to know how to search them recursively?

Comment: Please look at one of the 200 other nearly identical questions here.

Comment: @iMartin exactly search them recursively, get hold of the key "type". This is essential for me because this defines the widget for me and each widget has its own set of assets. Is there a way? Can you provide me the pseudo code?

Comment: To search them recursively you'd generally search them recursively.  If you don't know how to do a recursive search you need to study up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem is recursive search, you have to use **stack**. Here are the steps:

1. Create `NSMutableArray` that will serve as the stack. Now it is empty.
2. Take the root `widgets` array and put all its objects onto the stack (`-addObjectsFromArray:`).
3. Take out the first widget (`NSDictionary`) in stack. Be sure to take it **out of the stack** (`-removeObjectAtIndex:`) **after storing it in variable**.
4. Do your `type` comparision and other stuff with that variable.
5. Take its subwidgets and put all of them onto the stack just like *in step 2*.
6. If the stack has something in it, repeat from *step 3*. Otherwise you processed all widgets.

Pseudo code:

```
// 1
NSMutableArray *stack = [NSMutableArray array];
// 2
[stack addObjectsFromArray:rootWidgets];
while (stack.count > 0) {
    // 3
    NSDictionary *widgetDict = [stack objectAtIndex:0];
    [stack removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    // 4
    if ([[widgetDict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:...]) // Do whatever...
    // 5
    [stack addObjectsFromArray:[widgetDict objectForKey:@"widgets"]];
}
// 6
// You are done...
```

Comment: If i do step 3 for the first time its printing nothing, everything is removed right if I do [stackArray removeObjectatIndex :0] ??

Comment: If there is just one root widget, then it is OK. The stack will be empty, but in _step 5_ you add all subwidgets. If it does not have any, you come to _step 6_ and then you are done – there was only one widget in whole JSON.

Comment: If you look at the structure there is a root "widgets", after which there is again a child "widgets" with its own details and so on. After I have done step 3, there is no data being printed, so how should I do step 4?

Comment: Ah, yes. You take out the widget (the only root one), but store it in variable. I will update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Still this is not working, Its printing an empty array after the first check. I am trying to NSLog after step 5 The stack array is empty still

Comment: The stack ***is* empty**, but do **not** print stack. You **don't need** to print stack! Print that `widgetDict` variable, if you want to see something in the console. Or just move the `-removeObjectAtIndex:` before `// 5` and you will see the object in stack, but there will be no difference. The code works, but you are expecting wrong result at some point in the middle of loop.

Comment: Yeah my bad I figured it out that the stack will be empty thanks. But I have a question I am doing the "type" comparison in step 4, its printing the widgetDict, but how do I do the "type" comparison again because the type is not unique. It would be great if you clear this point out to me

Comment: Not sure, what so you mean by _do the "type" comparision again_. Your step `4` can be anything. You can make method for processing the widget and call it in step `4` like this `[self processWidget:widgetDict]`.

Answer (score 0):

To check the type of each element, use the `NSObject` `isKindOfClass:` method.

So, you might have something like:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { ... }
```

Or

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { ... }
```

Like @H2CO3 says, you use `objectAtIndex:` to access array elements and `objectForKey:` to access dictionary elements.

**EDIT:** I just realized that by "of a certain type" the OP meant the value of the "type" field, rather than the objective-c class of an entry. Still, it is often useful when reading JSON data to determine whether an entry is an array or dictionary, so I will leave my answer here.

Comment: Is there a way of getting hold of this ? I am a kind of stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

In the latest objective C you can use subscripting like C arrays.  For example,

```
NSLog(@"%@", widgetArray[i]);
```

For dictionaries you can extract via key:

```
NSString* id = myDict[@"id"];
```